# ThreadPool implementation in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, thread-safety

I have written a simple thread-pool implementation in C++ and want your comments to improve my understanding and improve my implementation. I understand I am repeating thread-pool implementation, but it is for putting my concepts to real perspective and learning.

#### "TPool.h"

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

class TPool;
class Task;

//reference of this interface is passed to the tasks being executed
//so that tasks can add new tasks to thread-pool
interface ITPoolTaskQueue
{
    void enQueueTask(Task& task);
    uint32_t countPendingTasks();
};

//task base class which can be inherited to create actual
//task which will be submitted to thread-pool by client code
class Task
{
public:
    virtual Task* clone() = 0;
    virtual void destroy(Task* t) = 0;
    virtual void execute(ITPoolTaskQueue& tpTasks) = 0;
};

//thread-pool class, which allows to init with number of threads
//as an arguent and allows to submit tasks to be executed by threads
class TPool : public ITPoolTaskQueue
{
    typedef std::unique_ptr<std::thread> ThreadPtr;
    typedef std::unique_ptr<Task> TaskPtr;
    typedef std::queue<TaskPtr> TaskQueue;

protected:
    TaskQueue _taskQ;                       //queue for storing tasks
    bool _stopThreads;                      //this flag is set to inform threads to exit
    std::mutex _mutexQ;                     //mutex used by task queue
    std::condition_variable _cvThread;      //condition variable to signal run and wait to threads
    std::vector<ThreadPtr> _threads;        //threads of thread-pool

    void destroyThread(ThreadPtr& thread);
    void createThread(ThreadPtr& thread);
    bool deQueueTask(TaskPtr& task);
    void clearQueue();

public:
    explicit TPool(unsigned int numberOfThreads = 0);
    virtual ~TPool();

    void init();
    void deInit();
    void threadFunction();                  //this will be called by each thread of thread-pool

    virtual void enQueueTask(Task& task);
    virtual uint32_t countPendingTasks();
};
```

#### "TPool.cpp"

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TPool.h"

TPool::TPool(unsigned int numberOfThreads)
{
    auto poolSize = 0 == numberOfThreads ? std::thread::hardware_concurrency() : numberOfThreads;

    while (poolSize--)
    {
        _threads.push_back(nullptr);
    }
}

TPool::~TPool()
{
    try
    {
        deInit();
    }

    catch (...)
    {}
}

void TPool::destroyThread(ThreadPtr& thread)
{
    if (thread.get() != nullptr)
    {
        if (thread->joinable())
        {
            thread->join();
        }

        thread.reset();
    }
}

void TPool::createThread(ThreadPtr& thread)
{
    thread = std::make_unique<ThreadPtr::element_type>(&TPool::threadFunction, this);
}

void TPool::init()
{
    _stopThreads = false;
    std::for_each(_threads.begin(), _threads.end(), [this](ThreadPtr& thread){createThread(thread);});
}

void TPool::deInit()
{
    _stopThreads = true;
    clearQueue();
    _cvThread.notify_all();
    std::for_each(_threads.begin(), _threads.end(), [this](ThreadPtr& thread){destroyThread(thread);});
    _threads.clear();
}

uint32_t TPool::countPendingTasks()
{
    return _taskQ.size();
}

void TPool::enQueueTask(Task& task)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutexQ);
    TaskPtr tptr(task.clone());
    _taskQ.push(std::move(tptr));
    _cvThread.notify_one();
}

bool TPool::deQueueTask(TaskPtr& task)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutexQ);

    if (_taskQ.empty())
    {
        task = nullptr;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        task = std::move(_taskQ.front());
        _taskQ.pop();
        return true;
    }
}

void TPool::clearQueue()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutexQ);
    while (!_taskQ.empty())
    {
        TaskPtr t;
        t = std::move(_taskQ.front());
        t->destroy(t.release());
        _taskQ.pop();
    }
}

void TPool::threadFunction()
{
    TaskPtr task(nullptr);

    while (!_stopThreads)
    {
        if (deQueueTask(task))
        {
            task->execute(*this);
            task->destroy(task.release());
        }
        else
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutexQ);
            _cvThread.wait(lock, [this]{return !_taskQ.empty() || _stopThreads; });
        }
    }
}
```

Some client test code

```
class EnmFolder : public Task
{
public:
    virtual Task* clone()
    {
        Task * t = new EnmFolder;
        return t;
    }

    virtual void destroy(Task* t)
    {
        delete t;
    }

    virtual void execute(ITPoolTaskQueue& tpTQ)
    {
    }

    std::string _folder;
};

void someTest()
{
    EnmFolder enumFolderTask;
    enumFolderTask._folder = "C:";
    TPool threadPool;

    threadPool.init();
    threadPool.enQueueTask(enumFolderTask);
    threadPool.enQueueTask(enumFolderTask);
    threadPool.enQueueTask(enumFolderTask);
    threadPool.enQueueTask(enumFolderTask);
    threadPool.enQueueTask(enumFolderTask);
    //require some way to wait here before deInit()
    threadPool.deInit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. Yes I use MSVS. I have not used CMake ever, will google and try to post a CMake solution. @Incomputable

Comment: I believe people already started reviewing this (the upvotes came quite fast), and our site generally prefers not updating code after its being posted, even after receiving answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use non-standard keywords if you can help it. Use of `interface` gratuitiously limits portability.
2. Anyway, I'm not sure why you decided to define the interface `ITPoolTaskQueue` at all, as there's only one implementation for it. If you forego it, you can eliminate the virtual dispath there.
3. Next, there's `Task`:

   1. I wonder why you would want to clone a task. Ah, because you only ever enqueue a copy. So, what do you expect will happen to the original after that?
   2. `destroy(Task* t)` has me flabbergasted. Why would you ask a `Task` to destroy another `Task`? And if it should destroy itself, why didn't you just call `delete` and used a virtual dtor?
   3. Why do you eschew `operator()` for executing a `Task`? Also, are you sure passing the thread-pool here instead of relying on the creator of the task passing everything needed is such a good idea? What if the task should use a different task-pool?
   4. Anyway, consider whether simply using `std::function` might not be superior to defining your own.
4. Now to `TPool`:

   1. `TaskQueue` is a simple private single-use typedef. Inlining it would help readability.
   2. Consider simplifying the interface: Integrate `init()` with the ctor, and `deinit()` with the dtor.
   3. `threadFunction()` seems to be an implementation-detail. Consider treating it as such.
   4. It's an error when the queue contains a nullpointer, so you can return a nullpointer to indicate failure to dequeue an element. Makes for a much nicer contract.
   5. `countPendingTasks()` is a data-race with concurrent enqueueing and dequeueing. You have to lock.
   6. You know you can create a vector filled with any number of default-constructed elements just by calling the ctor? And you also know that a default-constructed `std::thread` does not represent a thread?

Comment: Thank you for your thorough review comments. My comments:-   
1 and 2. Yes agreed   
  
3. Task:-   
1. Creating and destroying the original is client code's responsibility.   2. Since I had 'clone()', I added 'destroy()'. my reasoning was I dont know how clone was created so I dont know how to destroy the clone.  
3. Agreed, can use 'operator()' 4. Will try using 'std::function'  

4. TPool:-   
1. Ok   
2. Keeping them('ctor' and 'init') separate allows the flexibility to client to create pool object and actual threads.   
3. Please explain   
4,5 and 6. Ok
@Deduplicator

Comment: Well, 3.1 Well, the client-code supplies clone and destroy, so it does that either way. I'm just pointing out that the original will most likely be destroyed immediately after being cloned. 3.2 If you know it was created with new and it has a virtual dtor, that would be enough to delete it. 4.2 You can create an empty thread-pool (should add a constexpr noexcept default-ctor for that), and if needed swap it with a new one having loads of threads. 4.3 It's the run-function for your thread-pool-threads. Nobody outside the classes implementation should use it, so make it private.

Comment: thank you for time and comments. will implement them. @Deduplicator


waiting for others to review.